# Nestjs e2e test fails with getHttpServer but works with .agent

Tags: jestjs, nestjs

I was trying to write my first e2e test in nestjs using the following code:

```
describe('AppController (e2e)', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        AppModule,
      ]    
    }).compile();

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
    await getConnection().synchronize(true);
  });

  it('/ (GET)', async () => {
    return request(app.getHttpServer())
      .get('/')
      .expect(200);
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await app.close();
  });
});
```

It always fails with 404, when trying to debug the supertest request I saw:

```
{
   errno: -61,
   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
   syscall: 'connect',
   address: '127.0.0.1',
   port: 57523,
   response: undefined
 }
```

If I try to connect to the actual app using `.agent('127.0.0.1:3000')` the test passes.

```
  it('/ (GET)', async () => {
    return request
     .agent('127.0.0.1:3000')
     .get('/')
     .expect(200)
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to await the response. Do something like. Look at below snippet where i have added await to response instead of return

```
  it('should throw validation error when creating employer policy', async () => {
const data = {
  max_percent_of_salary: true,
  is_employer_paid: true,
  has_advance_activated: false,
};

const response = await request(app.getHttpServer())
  .post('/sa-employer-policy/create/')
  .set('Accept', 'application/json')
  .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + employer_token)
  .send(data)
  .expect(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

expect(response.body.message).toBeDefined();
```

});

Comment: thanks for the answer, await is not making any difference

Comment: await getConnection().synchronize(true); should be above the app.init

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using an endpoint from a controller without importing the parent module.

Comment: I have imported the controller in AppModule, but still getting this error. It works outside of tests. Could you post what exactly you did to solve this?